# jQuery custom breaks on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-plugins

Having the following jQuery countdown plugin I have a problem to update counter containers time countdown if there are more than one element initialized. In this case the last container is getting updated and the countdown seconds are incrased

The plugin codes

```
(function( $ ){

    var methods = {

        container: null,

        init : function(options) {
            var timestamp = $(this).data('release'), id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (!timestamp) return;

            methods.container = $('#' +id);
            console.log(methods.container)

            methods.times = {days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0};
            time = new Date();

            methods.secondsToGo = timestamp - Math.round(time/1000) + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);
            methods.calcTimes();
        },

        calcTimes: function() {
            secondsToGo = methods.secondsToGo;

            // Countdown end is in the past
            if (secondsToGo < 0) return;

            methods.container.show();

            // Calculate times
            methods.times.days  = Math.floor(secondsToGo/86400);
            if (this.times.days > 99) this.times.days = 99; // max. 2 digits
            secondsToGo = secondsToGo%86400;

            methods.times.hours = Math.floor(secondsToGo/3600);
            secondsToGo = secondsToGo%3600;

            methods.times.minutes  = Math.floor(secondsToGo/60);

            methods.times.seconds  = secondsToGo%60;

            methods.updateCounter();

            // Minus 1 second
            methods.secondsToGo--;

            // Loop
            setTimeout(function(){
                methods.calcTimes();
            }.bind(this), 1000);
        },

        updateCounter: function() {
            for(var prop in this.times) {
                pre = '';
                if (this.times[prop] < 10) pre = '0'; // min. 2 digits

                // number to string
                this.times[prop] = pre + this.times[prop];

                times = this.times; // ... because I can't use this.times in each-loop

                dnb = 0;

                methods.container.find('.number-block-' + prop).children('.number').each(function(){
                    $(this).html(times[prop][dnb]);
                    dnb++;
                })
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.countdown = function(methodOrOptions) {
        if ( methods[methodOrOptions] ) {
            return methods[ methodOrOptions ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || ! methodOrOptions ) {
            // Default to "init"
            $obj = this

            return this.each(function() {
                //$(this).append(' - ' + $(this).data('x'));
                methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
            });
            //return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.countdown' );
        }
    };


})( jQuery );
```

problem demonstration [codepen](http://codepen.io/deroccha/pen/kkvbzy)

the problem is the self update which is inside of plugins loop and thats how the update on containers has effect on the last loaded. What would be a wise workaround to update all container on each second?

Comment: I think putting $ inside the function parameter, as in `(function( $ ){`, is not a wise action

Comment: having removed(no changes), but why is bad if I pass the jQuery object to the anonymous function?